# How to send post request to remote server (ip) via web browser?

Tags: web, server, vps

I have bought remote VPS and i have telegram bot. I want to make email verification for this bot. So how should i send requests to scripts on the server when user clicks on the button "Verify" that contains some information about his telegram profile so i can approve him to use bot?

The main problem that i dont know how to send requests to scripts on the server by ip

There is no website on the server, maybe i should set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Ive realized that i can do it like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3eKN.png). But any contributions would be met with enthusiasm)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like youn need an RESTful API to authenticate users.
And a client...